# Copy and paste but insert lines and transpose some lines

Tags: excel, copy-paste, transpose, vba

I have in a spreadsheet detail of orders I wish need to convert into a different format. The data come across for example:
Customer    Order date  Product Order no    Line no Desc 1  Desc 2  Desc 3
B & Q   10 January  Ladder  1   1   Step ladder Grey    Short
B & Q   11 January  Paint   1   2   Outdoor Matt    Green
Tesco   8 January   Food    2   1   Picnic food Party   Jan

If possible I am looking for a macro that copies and pastes each line into multiple lines. So needs to create a header line for each unique customer record which contains customer ref/ order date. Then line below would contain customer ref product detail etc

Customer    Order date  Product Order no    Line no Narrative 
B & Q           1
    10 January  Ladder      1   Step ladder
                    Grey
                    Short
    11 January  Paint       2   Outdoor
                    Matt
                    Green
Tesco           2
    8 January   Food        1   Picnic food
                    Party
                    Jan

My vba is very basic I've tried using the record function but can't get it to be automated to move on to the next line. Other than pointing at specific cells and using a little transpose in copy and paste I can't get my head around moving it on. The source data can range from 50 lines to over 200.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Cat

Answer (score 0):

This code is kind of "brute force", but it does the trick.  I'm assuming that all your data is in row one, and that every record has 8 columns.  If those aren't true, I'm sure you can change the variables in this code to make it work with your data.

```
Sub RearrangeData()

' Set a couple of variables
iColToRead = 9  ' Start at 9 because the first 8 columns are headers
iRowToDisplay = 2   ' Start at 2 because row 1 has the source data

' Loop through the cells on row 1
Do While Cells(1, iColToRead).Value <> ""

    ' Loop through the columns
    For iColAdd = 0 To 7

        ' Copy the value from the first row to the corresponding cell in the destination row
        Cells(iRowToDisplay, iColAdd + 1).Value = Cells(1, iColToRead + iColAdd).Value

        ' Clear out the cell in the first row that was just copied
        Cells(1, iColToRead + iColAdd).Value = ""
    Next

    ' "Move" the next section in the source row
    iColToRead = iColToRead + 8

    ' "Move" to the next destination row
    iRowToDisplay = iRowToDisplay + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I included lots of comments so the code would make more sense. :)

Be sure to up-vote this answer or mark it as "correct" if it helps you!